# How do you convert a date to a number?

Tags: python, pandas

How do you convert a pandas dataframe column from a date formatted as below to a number as shown below:

```
        date 
0 4/5/2010     
1 9/26/2014     
2 8/3/2010
```

To this

```
        date newFormat
0 4/5/2010     40273
1 9/26/2014    41908
2 8/3/2010     40393
```

Where the second columns is the number of days since 1/1/1900.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a given ordinal number (from Excel) to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387137/how-to-convert-a-given-ordinal-number-from-excel-to-a-date)

Comment: To apply to a Series of dates you would: `(pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')-pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01')).dt.days`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
data['newFormat'] = data['Date'].dt.strftime("%Y%m%d").astype(int)
```

This has been answered before:
[Pandas: convert date 'object' to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863691/pandas-convert-date-object-to-int)
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863691/pandas-convert-date-object-to-int)

Comment: Does this result in the number of days since 1/1/1900?

Comment: @jarmod It does not, this is a bad copy-paste from a different question and does not answer OP's question at all. This results in 01/01/1970 being converted into the integer 01011970, which is very different from what OP is asking